Proof of multivariate polynomial is identically zero implies all coefficients are zero
I know that this implication for an equality of two polynomials extends from one variable to several variables, but how would someone prove this?
Is it as easy as proving for a single variable?

Assume a multivariate polynomial $P(x, ...)$ is equal to 0 at all points. In specific, this implies that
$P(x, 1, 1, ..., 1) = 0 \forall x$.
That's just a normal polynomial $Q(x)$ with the same coefficients as $P$ for all terms that contain $x$ (all other terms are constant summands).
Since $Q(x) = 0 \forall x$ (as we know for univariate polynomials), all coefficients of $Q$ are $0$.
Thus, all terms containing $x$ must have the coefficient $0$.
The same can be done for all other variables, showing that all coefficients must equal 0.

Let $p$ be a polynomial in $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. Pick any values for $x_1 = c_1, \ldots, x_{n-1} = c_{n-1}$ and define
$$ Q(x_n) = p(c_1, \ldots, c_{n-1}, x_n) $$
This is now a polynoimal in one variable (i.e., $x_n$).
We know that for all values of $x_n$, $Q(x_n) = 0$. Hence it is equal to the zero polynomial. Thus, all of the coefficients are equal to 0.
The coefficients of $Q$ are now polynomials in $n-1$ variables that are all identically zero. Hence we can reduce it to the 1 variable case.
